# Factorization of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, extension-field

I have been given these two polynomials
$$f(t)=t^3+2t+1 \text{ & }g(t)=t^3+t^2-t+2$$
the problem says, decide if both factorization fields are isomorphic. For the second polynomial I got that
$$g(t)=(t-1)(t-2)^2$$
and the first one is irreducible since it has degree 3 and no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so I guess that's enough to say that both fields are not isomorphic since the second one is $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and the first one isn't. Although I would like to explicitely compute $f$ factorization field just to see how it goes but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Edited the polynomial g.

Comment: Although, I don't see how both fields would be isomorphic if $g$ was irreducible. I think the extensions doesn't even need to have the same degree.

Comment: This is because every finite extension of a finite field is normal (meaning the extensions will have the same degree), and there is exactly one of each degree. So any two finite fields with the same cardinality are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3[\alpha]$, where $\alpha^3+2\alpha+1=0$, because $$t^3+2t+1=(t- \alpha) (t-\alpha+1) (t-\alpha-1)$$

Indeed, long division gives
$$
t^3+2t+1=(t- \alpha) (t^2+\alpha t+\alpha^2-1)
$$
and $\alpha^2-1=(\alpha+1)(\alpha-1)$ suggests that the roots of $t^2+\alpha t+\alpha^2-1$ are $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha-1$, which is true because $(\alpha+1)+(\alpha-1)=2\alpha=-\alpha$.

Comment: Yea I got that part, what I want is to compute the splitting field of $f$.

Comment: @Smurf, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

let $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in $\mathbb{E}\,$(An extended field of $\mathbb{Z}_3$). we have 
$$f(\alpha)^3=(\alpha^3+2\alpha+1)^3=\alpha^9+2\alpha^3+1=f(\alpha^3)=0$$
$$f(\alpha)^9=(\alpha^3+2\alpha+1)^9=\alpha^{18}+2\alpha^9+1=f(\alpha^9)=0$$
therefore $\alpha \,\, , \alpha^3$ and $\alpha^9$ are roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{E}\,$
we have
$$\mathbb{E}=\mathbb{Z}_3(\alpha)=\{a+x_1\alpha+x_2\alpha^2|a\,,\,x_i\in \mathbb{Z}_3\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you were asking about this but here comes anyway. As explained by others the splitting field of $f$ has 27 elements. It is $\Bbb{Z}_3[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of $f(x)$, in other words it satisfies the equation $\alpha^3-\alpha+1=0$. Alternatively you can think that I just denote the coset 
$x+\langle f(x)\rangle\in\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ by $\alpha$. To keep the notation simple! Note that because $0=3$ in this field we also have $-1=2$ and therefore $2x=-x$ in the polynomial ring.

To show that $K=\Bbb{Z}_3[\alpha]$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ you need either a bit of luck or to know about the Galois theory of the extension $K/\Bbb{Z}_3$. The latter implies that the other zeros of $f(x)$ are 
$$
\alpha^3=\alpha^3-0=\alpha^3-f(\alpha)=\alpha-1
$$
and
$$
\alpha^9=(\alpha-1)^3=\alpha^3-1^3=(\alpha-1)-1=\alpha+1.
$$
If you are knew to this it is a good exercise to check by hand that $\alpha\pm1$ are also zeros of $f(x)$.